# active record でサブクエリを使う方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

親テーブルで別々の条件でフィルタした子テーブルの共通レコードを取りたいんですが
Active Record でサブクエリはどう書けばいいんでしょうか

具体的にはこんな感じのクエリを投げたいです

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
  SELECT children.* FROM parents JOIN children WHERE ...
),
tmp2 AS (
  SELECT children.* FROM parents JOIN children WHERE ...
),
SELECT * FROM tmp1 JOIN tmp2 ON ...
```

---

ちなみに ActiveRecord Relation から実行せずにクエリだけ取り出したりってできないででしょうか？
全て active record でかかなくても以下のように SQL インジェクション が起こりそうなクエリだけ 
active record で生成してもいいかなと思うんですが

```
sql = <<EOS
WITH tmp1 AS (
  #{sub_query1}
),
tmp2 AS (
  #{sub_query2}
),
SELECT * FROM tmp1 JOIN tmp2 ON ...
EOS
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Relation#to_sql` が、求めているメソッドかな、と思っています。

> ちなみに ActiveRecord Relation から実行せずにクエリだけ取り出したりってできないででしょうか？

が実現できます。

Comment: できました！　ありがとうございます